# PHP 7 Non-static method

Tags: php, dependencies, non-static

Hello im having trouble with pagination in my site.

```
Deprecated: Non-static method Pagination::load() should not be called statically in /home/user/domains/123123/public_html/server.php on line 63
```

Here is my code on the line 63

```
$data = Pagination::load($numberOfElements, $currentPage, $elementsPerPage, $paginationWidth);
```

Comment: Is the Pagination class your own or are you using a framework?

Comment: Please show your Pagination class. To be called as static, the method must be prefixed with `static` keyword before the `function` keyword. Also it can not depend on any non static property and method from that class.